# Git fetch running forever

Tags: git, git-fetch

I have a repository named `old-repo` and a duplicate `new-repo`. Some work has been done on `old-repo`, which I want to port across to `new-repo`. I thought this would be easily done by adding `old-repo` as a remote and merging the changes, but `git fetch` is taking forever.

I don't think the repository very big; it is about 250MB, most of this is in the test data directory as `TIFF` images. There are also around 200 branches on the remote.

Running `git clone old-repo` takes ~10secs, but if I run the following steps:

```
$ git clone NEW_REPO_URL.git
$ cd new-repo
$ git remote add old-repo OLD_REPO_URL
$ git fetch old-repo -v --progress
```

the only output is:

```
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 32749 to 16521 bytes)
```

and there is no further progress, so I have to quit the job with `CTRL-C`.

I have tried pulling in just one branch `git fetch old-repo dev` or a shallow fetch `git fetch old-repo depth=1`, but when I try another command, like `git diff old-repo/dev`, I get the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'old-repo/dev': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Does anyone know why fetch might be running so slow? Or, if there is a way to only fetch the `dev` branch, so I can merge the changes (I'm not interested in all the other branches on the remote). I've tried searching in the internet, but most results are about clone being slow, which was not what I wanted.

EDIT - WORKAROUND:

I haven't found the solution yet, but do have a workaround. It is possible to use the locally-cloned repo instead of the remote:

```
git remote add old-repo ../old-repo
git remote update
```

This works fine, but the update procedure is slightly more complicated. Instead of `git pull old-repo dev`, you have to:

```
cd ../old-repo
git pull
cd ../new-repo
git remote update
git pull old-repo dev
```

Comment: As a sidenote, the number of branches is irrelevant here. You could as well have a hundred more without noticing a real performance difference.

Comment: How many time did you let `git fetch` command run?

Comment: @double-beep Not sure, about half an hour maybe. Much longer than 10s anyway.

Comment: Does your repository includes submodule(s)?